# Долгий запрос в InnoDB

Tags: mariadb, innodb

Имею следующий запрос в DB

```
  SELECT
  w.Number AS ID,
  mo.TargetHrs AS Montag,
  di.TargetHrs AS Dienstag,
  mi.TargetHrs AS Mittwoch,
  do.TargetHrs as Donnerstag
FROM link_avero.avero_weeklyprog w
  INNER JOIN link_avero.avero_dailyprog mo
    ON w.DPS1Mo = mo.Number
  INNER JOIN link_avero.avero_dailyprog di
    ON w.DPS1Tu = di.Number
  INNER JOIN link_avero.avero_dailyprog mi
    ON w.DPS1We = mi.Number
  INNER JOIN link_avero._avero_dailyprog do
    ON w.DPS1Th = do.Number
```

в InnoDB запрос выполняется от 15+ минут и выше.. такой же запрос через MSSQL обрабатывается в течении 10 секунд

Конфигурация серверов одинаковая
Конфиг InnoDB
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Индексы на месте? Смотрели план запроса?

Comment: @gil9red индексы на месте. Что вы подразумиваете под планом запроса?

Comment: У базы можно запросить не выполнение запроса, а его план, по которому она будет выполнять запроса и по нему можно увидеть, если запрос будет выполняться неоптимизировано

Comment: @gil9red не подкажите, как это сделать?

Comment: https://mariadb.com/kb/en/explain/